# Trace failed login attempts Windows Server

Tags: windows, security, server, active-directory

We have noticed ~15k failed login attempts a day on one of our admin-accounts in the domain.
The source server is found and the event type is "Network", the source is a DC that has not been touched (except WinUpd) for years so a virus seems unlikely but of course possible.

Is there a way to trace exactly what the failed attempts point at? We have recently changed FSMO roles between two other DCs in the domain, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

You can check the login failed attemps based in audit logon events local computer policy.

use the keyboard shortcut Windows Key + R and type:gpedit.msc in the Run line and hit Enter.

In Group Policy Editor, navigate to Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Local Policy >> Audit Policy.

Then double click on Audit Logon Events.

[image]

From there, check the boxes to audit failed audit attempts and click OK.

There you go! Now you’ll be able to see the complete logon activities (failed l) for your Windows computer.

Please refer this one as well based on event id you can know exactly what the failed attempts point at. : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f49cd4d6-a7d5-4213-8482-72d1d5306dab/windows-server-2012-r2-help-finding-failed-logon-attempts-source?forum=winserversecurity

Reference: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/pin-windows-8-start-screen-programs-desktop/